# Why is not a question highlighted although the tags are among the favourite ones?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface, user-experience

See the section of my favourite tags. Aside of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) there is [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) with [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot).

Then I filter the questions tagged with [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) and the soft-yellow highlighting disappears at all the questions which are not tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Is it because [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is somehow my "top" of the favourite tags, so is automatically offered as the best choice?

How the highlighting works? It quite confuses me and makes my eyes skip the not highlighted questions.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone used inspect element to give themselves some rep and badges :P

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Shhh, the next time keep the secret to yourself >,<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions with *the tag you are currently looking at the results of* are not highlighted.  If they were, then every single question on the list would be highlighted, and the highlighting wouldn't mean anything.  It highlights questions in one of your favorited tags *if you're not currently on the question list of that tag*.  So those two questions *would* be highlighted if you were looking at them from the homepage, or the [spring-data-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) tag or one of those other tags.

Comment: Makes a perfect sense. Thank you :)